# Cache only for regular not for registered user ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, outputcache, cache-control

I cache different versions on server of some pages using cache profile, for differing versions I am using VaryByCustom parameter which is overloaded and returns one version for registered user and another for common one. As it turns out my registered users will soon have very different information on page. My question is it possible to say if user is registered than do not cache anything?

Comment: When you say "registered", do you mean "currently signed in"?

Comment: yes that is what i meant, that does not even matter it can be even by some type of user(users differed by some property they have or not by role they are in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string custom)
{
    if ("User".Equals(custom, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name))
            return Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); // do not cache anything
        return string.Empty; // cache for non-signed-in users
    }
    return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, custom);
}
```

**Reply to comments**

GUID is Globally Unique IDentifier. Each time you invoke `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()`, you will get a pretty darn unique string. **Technically, the result will still be cached**, however it will be cached using the unique string. So, chances are infintesimally low that 2 signed-on users would ever see the same cached result. In fact, chances are equally low that the same signed-on user would ever see a cached result for the page.

Another approach, if you do not want to cache anything at all, would be to implement caching manually. However, I don't think you can tell an action method to "cache for non-signed in users, but don't cache for signed-on users" using the `OutputCacheAttribute`.

Comment: Thanks i will try this, it is not just clear to me why he will not cache anything when you say: return Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

Comment: Thanks, maybe the best option then is to cache for every user different version that way at least i wont be using memory in vain. Thanks a lot once again.

Comment: Yes, that is what we do -- return `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name` from the `GetVaryByCustomString` override for the `"User"` string. This way, each user gets their own cached version of the page, and anonymous users all share a separate cached version.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out you can stop caching for signed in user, by implementing custom caching provider in witch you can on Add, Set, Remove method prevent caching of anything. Also you can very caching providers by user in global.asax. Only reason why i never used this approach is that i still needed caching of some pages for user, and i did not find the way to discover what is the current caching profile in the caching provider class so i could cache or not cache based on the profile. If for some reason you just want to prevent caching for signed user on every page i think this is the better approach then vary by custom approach using GUID.